# remove after and before ip addresses

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete everything except IPs.

For example

```
1 138.68.161.60:1080 SOCKS5 HIA United States (New York NY) 138.68.161.60 (DigitalOcean, LLC) 0.143 75% (3) - 12-jan-2018 14:37 (10 minutes ago)

2 174.64.234.29:17501   SOCKS5  HIA United States   wsip-174-64-234-29.sd.sd.cox.net (Cox Communications Inc.)  0.956   
    100% (5) -  12-jan-2018 14:36 (10 minutes ago)

3 45.79.219.154:63189   SOCKS5  HIA United States (Atlanta GA)  li1318-154.members.linode.com (Linode, LLC) 6.973   
    90% (103) - 12-jan-2018 14:36 (11 minutes ago)
```

to

```
138.68.161.60:1080

174.64.234.29:17501

45.79.219.154:63189
```

I need a regex to this convert.

Comment: Before asking this question have you tried anything ?

Comment: no
because i don't have regex for this
I need a general regex (for all proxy sites because i want extract proxies from this sites)

and

how you edit my message to this style?

Comment: You should at least try something and then post you question. No wonder your question is attracting down votes because it's without research. I didn't edited your question.

Comment: Users on StackOverflow may choose to edit posts to make them more readable, such as by adding code blocks with `accents`. It's all described in the top of the post while you create it :)

Comment: How about the second IP in the first line, you do not want it to make it into output?

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, it requires some finesse to delete text not containing matched strings, but you can choose `Find`, `Mark`, then check the `Regular expression` box and use the regex:
`([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}+)` and `Mark All`to bookmark all rows containing IP adresses.

Then select `Find`, `Replace`, enter `^[0-9]\W` in `Find what:`, and `Replace All` with nothing.

Then select `Find`, `Replace`, enter `\w+S.+` in `Find what:`, and `Replace All` with nothing.

Then, go to `Search`, `Bookmark`, `Remove Unmarked Lines`.

Et Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex in notepad++ and replace the captured values with group 1 `\1`

[`(?s)(\d \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+).*?\(\d+ minutes ago\)`](https://regex101.com/r/BD1txr/1/)

You select all the text for each of the 3 blocks from your example and use a capturing group for the text that you want to keep. Then in the replace you use only the captured group which holds your data.

**Explanation**

- Inline modifier to make the dot match a line break  `(?s)`
- Group 1 with the pattern that you want to capture `(\d \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+)`
- Match any character zero or more times non greedy `.*?`
- The pattern that is at the end of every part `\(\d+ minutes ago\)`